# How to handle errors that is caused by old data structure?

Tags: error-handling, errors

When a major data structure has been changed in an app, what is the best way to handle such kind of errors in the front-end side so that the app doesn’t break?

For example, we have a list of users that used to have this structure:

```
user: {
    firstname: “John”,
    lastname: “Doe”,
         // … some other properties
}
```

And then then data structure changed to:

```
someuser: {
    username: “abcA”,
         // … some other properties 
}
```

Now if I go to a user’s detail that’s using the old schema in the DB, the application will break since there’s no more such thing as `user`.

Of course, we can have a ‘default’ error page for all unexpected / unhandled errors. But this is something that we actually expect (cos of old data structure).

Should this be handled better in the front-end side as in, we have a condition to detect if this object is using the old schema? If so, show a more specific error message OR provide a way for that object to convert into the new schema?

What’s the best practice for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expect the old data structure to exist in production, and care at all about keeping users then yes, *of course* you need to provide a way to convert the data. You can't just say "sorry, we changed our software, all your data is invalid".

And this conversion should absolutely not happen in the frontend - data formats is a backend issue.

There are basically two ways to do it, each with advantages and disadvantages:

1. When you deploy the version that introduces the change, you migrate all the old data to the new format with a script.

   - Advantages: clean solution, no need to introduce complications in the code that works with the data.
   - Disadvantages: pretty much requires downtime while the conversion runs.
2. In the backend code that loads the data from the DB, have a condition that recognizes the old format and converts it (optionally also write back the new format)

   - Advantages: no downtime needed
   - Disadvantages: uglier code, and if you have multiple changes in data structures over time it can get *very* ugly.